# Can the new "ledge-grabbing" feature be disabled?

Tags: turok-2-seeds-of-evil-2017

The developer Night Dive Studios added a new "ledge grabbing" feature to their [2017 remaster of Turok 2: Seeds of Evil](http://store.steampowered.com/app/405830):

> Improved character speed and manoeuvrability [sic], including the ability to grapple ledges.

The feature is similar to modern Far Cry games. According to players it not only makes platforming easier, but also increases the jump range, allowing taking shortcuts to secret areas and perhaps even bypassing parts of the levels completely (Turok 2 features numerous locked doors which can only be opened with a specific item, reminiscent of other FPS games from the era).

According to [numerous complaints on the Steam discussion forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/405830/discussions/search/?q=ledge&include_deleted=1) there was no configuration setting for this attribute — is there now? "Ledge grabbing" isn't mentioned on [the patch notes](https://steamcommunity.com/app/405830/announcements/).

---

Improvements to the new version are so significant that I don't have much desire to search for [the original retail copy](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Turok_2:_Seeds_of_Evil):

> New Multiplayer
>
> - The new Multiplayer mode lets you battle with your friends. Using the best levels, weapons, and visuals from both the PC and Nintendo 64
>     versions, players will encounter a fun and visceral multiplayer
>     experience.
> - Players can also choose between a few skins for their character in combat. Network multiplayer is available through Steam, GOG Galaxy,
>     LAN and direct IP with cross play capabilities.
> - Split-screen mode is also available in network multiplayer. Lastly, a new multiplayer game mode called “Last Turok Standing” has been
>     added.
>
> New Game Engine
>
> - Ported to the Kex Engine 3.4.
> - Full 64-bit compatibility.
> - Brand new UI system.
>
> New Graphics System
>
> - Modernized deferred renderer.
> - Shadow maps and compiled light maps.
> - Screen-space reflections on textures and materials.
> - Dynamic and fixed-resolution sub/super-sampling.
> - New decals and effects.
>
> Enhanced Gameplay
>
> - Improved character speed and manoeuvrability [sic], including the ability to grapple ledges.
> - Updated maps.
> - Improved AI.
> - "Quick warp" feature allows instant travel to any previously visited portal.
> - Save and load anywhere.

Comment: Yes, a couple of users have said that ledge grabbing is now optional, but I want to see an reliable source or a screenshot of the options menu before purchasing the game. This version is marketed as a remaster, not a remake.